# AVAssetExportSession Trimmed Audio shows wrong duration metadata iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avassetexportsession

I'm using the code at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1730/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010629 to trim audio and it was working until the iOS 7 update. The media gets cropped to the correct duration and plays as such but when it is viewed in iTunes the cropped clip shows up with duration metadata that is the same as the original audio file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *titleMetadata = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
titleMetadata.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
titleMetadata.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle;
titleMetadata.value = @"Title";

AVMutableMetadataItem *durationMetadata = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
durationMetadata.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceID3;
durationMetadata.key = AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyLength;
durationMetadata.value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:30.0];


NSArray *metadeta = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleMetadata,durationMetadata, nil];

exporter.metadata = metadeta;
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Have exact same problem here